# FastCGI sent in stderr: "WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!"

Tags: django, nginx, fastcgi

I'm using NGINX + FASTCGI + DJANGO and in my NGINX error logs I see this error:

**FastCGI sent in stderr: "WSGIServer: missing FastCGI param SERVER_PROTOCOL required by WSGI!"**

Found [this solution](http://adminsgoodies.com/nginx-django-fastcgi-wsgi-error-non-fatal/) to apparently the same problem but I already have those lines on my nginx.conf file and still gives me the above error.

Any ideas? Thank you!

Comment: Where did you exactly added it in the config?

Comment: @petermolnar thank you for pushing me to look where exactly I added it. By doing that I just realized that SERVER_PROTOCOL actually wasn't there. Not sure where I looked last time but it certainly wasn't in the main nginx.conf file. I've added the line and now the error went away. Thank you again!

Answer (score 1):

You also need to add the following line to the location block in your nginx configuration

fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;

So the four you need are:

```
fastcgi_param SERVER_ADDR $server_addr;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PORT $server_port;
fastcgi_param SERVER_NAME $server_name;
fastcgi_param SERVER_PROTOCOL $server_protocol;
```